# prevent different user to see a model through the show method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my index method for every model I make sure to query starting with current user: current_user.model.all, in order to only show models that belong to the current user.

My show method for all models is quite simple and standard, without current_user.

```
  def show
    @logica = Logica.find params[:id]
    authorize @logica
  end
```

This does open the chance of a user entering a random id in the url and see the model from a different user. What is the best way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [has_many](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many) association has a number of different methods available including `find`

```
current_user.model.find(params[:id])
```

which is similar to

```
Model.where(user_id: current_user.id).find(params[:id])
```

If you have to go through several models in order to reach your User model, for instance

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :test_one
end

class TestOne < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :test_three
  belongs_to :user
end

class TestThree < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :test_fours
  belongs_to :test_one
end

class TestFour < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :test_three
end
```

you can set it up in a single query by doing something like

```
TestFour.joins(:test_three => { :test_one => :user }).where(test_threes: { test_ones: { users: { id: current_user.id}}}).find(1)
#  TestFour Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "test_fours".* FROM "test_fours" INNER JOIN "test_threes" ON "test_threes"."id" = "test_fours"."test_three_id" INNER JOIN "test_ones" ON "test_ones"."id" = "test_threes"."test_one_id" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "test_ones"."user_id" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 AND "test_fours"."id" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["id", 1], ["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
#=> #<TestFour id: 1, test_three_id: 1, created_at: "2017-07-12 21:06:51", updated_at: "2017-07-12 21:06:51">
```

and then if you did this with a user id/test four id that don't match:

```
TestFour.joins(:test_three => { :test_one => :user }).where(test_threes: { test_ones: { users: { id: current_user.id + 1}}}).find(1)
#  TestFour Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "test_fours".* FROM "test_fours" INNER JOIN "test_threes" ON "test_threes"."id" = "test_fours"."test_three_id" INNER JOIN "test_ones" ON "test_ones"."id" = "test_threes"."test_one_id" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "test_ones"."user_id" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 AND "test_fours"."id" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["id", 2], ["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
#=> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find TestFour with 'id'=1 [WHERE "users"."id" = $1]
```

Comment: How is that working performance wise? From current_user I'll have to go through 3 sometimes 4 different relationships in order to get to the model I want. Is there a big penalty?

Comment: @Rudi if you did it through the associations, it would fire off several SQL queries. I've updated my answer with an example of going through several models (`TestOne` and `TestThree`) to load a model `TestFour` only if the `user_id` matches the current user

Comment: Also, as Jason Brodie mentioned a gem like `CanCan` is really nice for restricting access and [even looks like](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/defining-abilities#hash-of-conditions) you can go through associations (just as in my last example) to set up restrictions as well, though I've never done anything complex like that with it, so not sure precisely how you'd set up an equivalent example and how well it does.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I'm using pundit (like can can) to restrict access, but that is more restriction based on certain roles, not so much the restriction we're talking about here.

Comment: @Rudi Yeah I saw you had an `authorize` method so assumed you were using something, but just wanted to make sure I mentioned gems like that exist and are pretty nice for this sort of thing, in case it was some custom action you had that just did some simple checks by hand